# Accessing HttpClientHandler.Credentials on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, basic-authentication, .net-6.0

I'm trying to implement basic authentication on a Web API server and a client that calls the API.

This is how I'm configuring my `HttpClient` object in my client code (note how I'm setting the credentials).

```
services.AddHttpClient<TrackAndTraceClient>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.Username, settings.Password),
        };
    });
```

However, this results in no *Authorization* header being received on the server end.

My question is, what does setting the credentials this way actually do? Where are those credentials placed?

And is it possible to write my server so that it handles credentials configured this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can add *Authorization* header to your client-side code as follows:

```
services.AddHttpClient<TrackAndTraceClient>()
     .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
     {
         httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
         httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
         var authenticationBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{settings.Username}:{settings.Password}");
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authenticationBytes));
     });
```

You can use [AuthenticationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to check *Authorization* header on the server side. Here is an [example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/05/19/net-5-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) of how to implement Basic Authentication using AuthenticationHandler.

Comment: I already have code that does this. My questions were 1. Where are credentials placed when I set the `Credentials` property, and 2. How can I configure the server to read credentials set that way.

Answer (score 0):

The `PreAuthenticate` should send the authentication header.

```
services.AddHttpClient<TrackAndTraceClient>()
 .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
 {
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl);
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
 })
 .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider =>
 {
    return new HttpClientHandler()
    {
      PreAuthenticate = true,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(settings.Username, 
       settings.Password)
    };
 });
```

If that does not work, it may be due to the `Credentials` property in the `HttpClientHandler` class having the`[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]` attribute (as of .NET 5) -- note so does the `PreAuthenticate` property. In addition, the `HttpClientHandler` class also contains the following definition:

> The default message handler used by HttpClient in .NET Framework and .NET Core 2.0 and earlier.

I see that your post has the tag `.NET 6`, so that might could also be a factor on why it's not sending. If I was you, I would use a middleware to rece9ve the authentication header from the request and use the solution @Burhan Savci posted for sending it.

Assuming your backend is a .NET Core API similar:

```
public class BasicAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public BasicAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
       _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string authHeader = 
            httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            string auth = authHeader.Split(new char[] { ' ' })[1];
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
            var usernameAndPassword = 
               encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth));
            string username = usernameAndPassword
                .Split(new char[] { ':' })[0];
            string password = usernameAndPassword
                 .Split(new char[] { ':' })[1];
            if (username == "abc" && password == "123")
            {
               await _next(httpContext);
            }
            else
            {
               httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
               return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the configure method of your Startup class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in actually trying this. First off, setting `PreAuthenticate = true` does not work. What's interesting is that I'm calling a third-party API with exactly the same approach and it works fine. But when it calls my Web API, there is no *Authorization* header. My Web API implements basic authentication according to [this article](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/how-to-add-basic-authentication-to-asp-net-core-application). I'm confused why I'd need additional middleware.