# AddHttpClient with HttpClientHandler, 401 unauthorized C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, credentials, http-status-code-401

I try to use `service.AddHttpClient` to create HttpClient and DI into my other services, but HttpClient need to be set credential informations.
Here is my step,

1. Startup.cs

   ```
    services.AddHttpClient("ServiceOne", x => {})
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => 
            {    var handler = new HttpClientHandler(){ 
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("account", "password")
                    };

                 return handler;
            });
   ```

2.ServiceOne.cs

```
public class ServiceOne : IService
{
 private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
}

public ServiceOne (IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
   this._clientFactory = clientFactory;
}

public string SomeFunction ()
{
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"http://uri");
  var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("ServiceOne");
  var response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

I received 401 Unauthorized, it seems the `HttpClientHandler` not be set correct.
Hope someone could help me this question, Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to test the connection using a browser or Postman or some other tool?

Comment: Yes, I test it using Postman.
This project use angular framework, when use ```withCredentials: true```, it received 200 OK.

Comment: Why are you setting `UseDefaultCredentials = true` when you want to specify the credentials yourself? I imagine that isn't the cause of your issue, but it seems like a strange thing to be doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116609/accessing-httpclienthandler-credentials-on-the-server

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Hi, I removed this setting just now, but still got a 401. Maybe you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use Fiddler (or a similar tool) to capture the request sent from Postman. Then use it to capture the request sent from your program. Compare them. Address any differences.